# Align horizontally and vertically in a circle

Tags: css, responsive-design, center, vertical-alignment, geometry

Following an example found over at CSS Tricks, I'm trying to center align content that is inside a circle container that is responsive. The example doesn't seem to be able to handle much content, and immediately breaks as soon as I enter more than a few lines of text.

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/trFam)

Inside the circle I need to have a header and a paragraph. Is there any way to set a max width of this content so that it isn't placed outside the circle when it doesn't fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set top value accordingly in your `.content` [code pen](http://cdpn.io/Hrbnv)

**Edit**

Do this changes:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;

}
.content span{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Now short text or long text that all will be centered now.

[check this](http://cdpn.io/mdfAz)

Comment: Thanks, that worked although I can't seem to make the value dynamic. Maybe its just not possible.

Comment: Had to reopen this question as I couldn't get the vertical centering to work. See my updated question with an example.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I tried your example above but the span content is just placed in the top, and not centered vertically. Using Chrome, latest version.

Comment: Seems to differ from browsers, FF displays the span content vertically centered but noth Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Ok for some reason I can't embed a JSFiddle link in my question so putting it here - http://jsfiddle.net/KTrZT/

Comment: Set your width and height in pixel to your .content then it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this must be a responsive solution. I can't use fixed pixel measurements. Thanks for the help though, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I created a new thread, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/clqzB. Not sure if this approach would work?